# issue running applications QT5

Tags: qt5, ubuntu-22.04

I am new to linux (ubuntu), I don't know what I did, but now I am having some applications not running, example for freecad the error is as follows:

`freecad: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN15QNetworkRequestC1Ev, version Qt_5`

I am running Ubuntu 22.04

the output of: `ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Qml.so.5` is:

```
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f8036c00000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f8036600000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8036200000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f80374a5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8036fe0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8035e00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f803749e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8036fc4000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007f8036faf000)
    libicui18n.so.70 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.70 (0x00007f8035a00000)
    libicuuc.so.70 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.70 (0x00007f8035805000)
    libpcre2-16.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007f8036b71000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f8036531000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f80360c6000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f80375aa000)
    libicudata.so.70 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.70 (0x00007f8033a00000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f80364b9000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @steeldriver in askubuntu for his help, basically I have browsed the applications on `/usr/local` and I found one that had the `libQt5Network.so.5` file.

I have uninstalled the application and now everything is back to normal.